# Ansible error due to GMP package version on Centos6

Tags: centos, docker, centos6, gmp, ansible

I have a Dockerfile that builds an image based on `CentOS` (tag: `centos6`):

```
FROM centos

RUN rpm -iUvh http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/x86_64/epel-release-6-8.noarch.rpm
RUN yum update -y
RUN yum install ansible -y

ADD ./ansible /home/root/ansible

RUN cd /home/root/ansible;ansible-playbook -v -i hosts site.yml
```

Everything works fine until Docker hits the last line, then I get the following errors:

```
 [WARNING]: The version of gmp you have installed has a known issue regarding
timing vulnerabilities when used with pycrypto. If possible, you should update
it (ie. yum update gmp).


PLAY [all] ******************************************************************** 

GATHERING FACTS *************************************************************** 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/ansible-playbook", line 317, in <module>
    sys.exit(main(sys.argv[1:]))
  File "/usr/bin/ansible-playbook", line 257, in main
    pb.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/ansible/playbook/__init__.py", line 319, in run
    if not self._run_play(play):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/ansible/playbook/__init__.py", line 620, in _run_play
    self._do_setup_step(play)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/ansible/playbook/__init__.py", line 565, in _do_setup_step
    accelerate_port=play.accelerate_port,
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/ansible/runner/__init__.py", line 204, in __init__
    cmd = subprocess.Popen(['ssh','-o','ControlPersist'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/subprocess.py", line 642, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/subprocess.py", line 1234, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Stderr from the command:

    package epel-release-6-8.noarch is already installed
```

I imagine that the cause of the error is the `gmp` package not being up to date.
There is a related issue on GitHub: https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/6941

But there doesn't seem to be any solutions at the moment ...
Any ideas ?
Thanks in advance !

My `site.yml` playbook:

```
- hosts: all

  pre_tasks:
    - shell: echo 'hello'
```

Comment: That doesn't look like gmp is related to the problem to me. That looks like that `ssh` command failed on a file that doesn't exist to me.

Comment: I'm not sure what to do in this case. My `Dockerfile` is fairly basic so it shouldn't really block the ssh connection no ?

Comment: That issue appears to be from ansible-playbook itself. Does that `hosts` file exist wherever ansible-playbook would be looking for it? Beyond that guess someone more familiar with ansible (or possibly docker though I doubt it) would need to weigh in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that the files `site.yml` and `hosts` are present in the directory you're adding to `/home/root/ansible`.

Side note, you can simplify your Dockerfile by using `WORKDIR`:

```
WORKDIR /home/root/ansible
RUN ansible-playbook -v -i hosts site.yml
```